# how to set axes dimension dynamically

Tags: matlab, plot

i have an axes in my GUI program, that xlimmode and ylimmode, should be manual at first, and when a user click on the button thye should be auto, anyone has idea? in other word, how should i set xlimmode dynamically? i try this code but it dosent work:

> ```
> set(gca,'XLimMode','auto')
> ```

and another question is how can i plot a quadratic equation like:

> 4+3x+8y+9x^2+18y^2=0

thank u in advance

Comment: these should be two separate questions..

Comment: For your second question: solve for y, then define a range of x and derive y from your solved equation. Then use the paired variables with plot. (http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/plot.html)

Answer (score 2):

To answer your first question, setting the [limit-mode](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/axes_props.html#zmw57dd0e32395) back to auto should work.. Here is an example to show:

```
plot(rand(10,1))
set(gca, 'XLim',[1 10], 'YLim',[0 1], ...
    'XLimMode','manual', 'YLimMode','manual')
uicontrol('Style','pushbutton', 'String','auto', ...
    'Callback','set(gca, ''XLimMode'',''auto'', ''YLimMode'',''auto'')')
```

If we plot something outside the current range (before pushing the button), the axes will not scale to show the new data.

```
hold on
plot(30:49, rand(20,1)*5)
hold off
```

If you click the button, the axis will automatically adjust (based on the XData/YData properties).

[image]